# Is it correct "I have been reading the book three hours."?

Tags: prepositions, time

Compare the two sentences below：

> A: I have been reading the book **for three hours**.
>
> B: I have been reading the book **three hours**.

I know A is obviously correct. But my question is:

- ***Is B also correct?***
- ***If yes, is there any subtle difference between them two?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example B is not natural, and would sound odd to a fluent speaker. I am inclined to say that it is grammatically incorrect.

Example A requires some previous context that specifies what book is being referred to. In the absence of such context "the book" is not correct, and "a book" or perhaps "this book" would be better.

If "The Book" is used with capitals, it **might** refer to the Christian Bible.